# Spring MVC + Hibernate: id to load is required for loading

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

This is such a noob question, I know and I apologize. I'm trying to edit existing record with Hibernates session.merge() method and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
```

This is my object:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TITLE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer titleId;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "TITLE_DESCRIPTION", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String titleDescription;
// default constructor, getters & setters
```

This is service layer method:

```
 public void edit(Title title) {
     logger.debug("Editing existing title");

     // Retrieve session from Hibernate
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

     // Retrieve existing title via id
     Title existingTitle = (Title) session.get(Title.class, title.getTitleId());

     // Assign updated values to this title
     existingTitle.setTitleDescription(title.getTitleDescription());

     // Save updates
     session.merge(existingTitle);
 }
```

This is controller POST method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postEditTitle(@Valid @ModelAttribute("titleAttribute") Title title,
                        BindingResult result) {

    logger.debug("Received request to edit title");

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "editTitle";
    }
    else {
        titleService.edit(title);
        return "redirect:/essays/main/title";
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're right @PaulHicks, `title.getTitleId()` is null! But I don't know why...

Comment: Upgraded my comment to an answer

Comment: It's shame on this site that you have to apologize first to ask a question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem isn't with Hibernate.  `title.getTitleId()` is null when you pass it to `session.get()`, and that's a problem with your web service/application.

1. Your GET might not be providing the id in the model object
2. Your client code (form, client app, ajax call, whatever it is) might not be retaining the ID between the GET and POST
3. Your POST might not be providing the id in the model object.

You can provide more details here, or ask a new question, if you're having difficulties retaining attributes across the web, rest or WS session.

Comment: I just added hidden input for `titleId` to my view and now it's working, so I guess 2nd one applies. Is there perhaps a more elegant way to do this, without adding hidden fields? @PaulHicks

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with that area, but that is a solution I have seen in older applications.  I guess it was once the standard way of doing things.  With newer frameworks (I'm thinking of AngularJS, but I know that others do the same thing) this isn't usually necessary.