# CDI + DeltaSpike Interceptor not working after Maven install

Tags: maven, javabeans, cdi, interceptor, deltaspike

I have a strange issue after using mvn install in my project.

If I run mvn clean before all, and I start my project inside Eclipse, I have not problem.

After running mvn install (I need this command to generate jar with assembly) and restarting project, I have strange exceptions saving data with hibernate because the transaction is not open.

One of this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
    at com.econorma.ft2500.util.concurrent.UserTransactionRunnable.run(UserTransactionRunnable.java:20)
    at com.econorma.ft2500.util.concurrent.ContextAwareExectuor$CDIRunnable.run(ContextAwareExectuor.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2548)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.EntityManager$827868750$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.econorma.ft2500.MeasureCache$UpdateLatestMeasure.runInTransaction(MeasureCache.java:136)
    at com.econorma.ft2500.util.concurrent.UserTransactionRunnable.run(UserTransactionRunnable.java:16)
    ... 8 more
```

Here is my beans.xml placed correctly in src/main/resources/META-INF:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
<interceptors>
    <class>com.econorma.ft2500.cdi.SynchronizedInterceptor</class>
    <class>org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

Transactional Class:

```
public abstract class UserTransactionRunnable implements Runnable{

    protected @Inject EntityManager em; 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        try{
            runInTransaction();
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            transaction.rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }finally{

        }

    }

    protected abstract void runInTransaction();
}
```

My consideration is that mvn install command generating TARGET folder lost connection to beans.xml.

Comment: Could you post your full exception stacktrace? That would be helpful for others to narrow down your problem and did you try debugging it? And make sure your table doesn't have invalid/non-id columns.

Comment: In my opinion is not a definition fields problem. Anyway I attached one of the exceptions I got because transaction is not open.

Comment: Have you tried lazy loading the entity using [FetchType.Lazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate) and make sure you are not passing null id in the `find()`  method.[Related Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21506213/1793718)

Comment: Yes I'm using Lazy annotation. Id is really null in find method, because previous save not working as well.  I don't find ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy that might be active.

Comment: I don't understand the role of the interceptor - does it open transaction? If you think beans.xml is missing after running mvn install, check the generated artefact, whether it realm contains beans.xml in META-INF folder or for WAR it should be in WEB-INF and not in META-INF

Comment: Could you post your `UserTransactionRunnable`?  It seems like you're saying your save doesn't work.  Can you show us your save?

Comment: This problem happens in Eclipse only after launched MVN CLEAN INSTALL. Transaction is not open. If I clear projects inside Eclipse and relaunch everything is ok. BEANS.XML inside jar is present and

Comment: Are you spanning a resource-local transaction over multiple threads?