# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is my updateUser controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/edit-user-{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String updateUser(@Valid User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model, @PathVariable Long id) {
            model.addAttribute("edit", true);
            model.addAttribute("success", "User " + userForm.getFirstName() + " " + userForm.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
            userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return "forward:/registration";
            }
            userService.updateUser(userForm);
            model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);

            return "registrationSuccess";
    }
```

this one is my addDocuments method

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/add-document-{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addDocuments(@PathVariable Long id, ModelMap model) {
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        try {
            if (user.getUsername() != null && !user.getUsername().equals(context.getUserPrincipal().getName())) {
                return "login";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new DocumentNotFoundException("No document found with that id or userName");
        }
        model.addAttribute("user", user);

        FileBucket fileModel = new FileBucket();
        model.addAttribute("fileBucket", fileModel);

        List<Catalog> documents = catalogService.findAllByUserId(id);
        model.addAttribute("documents", documents);

        return "manageDocuments";
}
```

when there is binding result error in updateUser method, it enters the "registration.jsp"

and at that time when I press add document button, it throws this kind of exception

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading.
```

this is registration jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="comment" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Create an account</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="${contextPath}/logout">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm" class="form-signin">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${edit}">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading"><spring:message code= "account.edit.label"/></h2>
            </c:when>

            <c:otherwise>
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading"><spring:message code= "account.create.label"/></h2>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

        <c:if test="${!edit}">
            <spring:bind path="username">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                    <form:input type="text" path="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                                autofocus="true"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="username"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
        </c:if>
        <spring:bind path="firstName">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="text" path="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"
                            autofocus="true"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="firstName"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="lastName">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="text" path="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"
                            autofocus="true"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="lastName"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="email">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="text" path="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
                            autofocus="true"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="email"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="skypeID">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="text" path="skypeID" class="form-control" placeholder="Skype ID"
                            autofocus="true"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="skypeID"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="password">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="passwordConfirm">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="password" path="passwordConfirm" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="passwordConfirm"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <c:if test="${edit}">
            <span class="well pull-left">
                <a href="<c:url value='/add-document-${userForm.id}' />" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><spring:message code= "button.upload.text"/></a>
            </span>
        </c:if>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"><spring:message code= "button.submit.label"/></button>
        <h3><a onclick="document.forms['logoutForm'].submit()"><spring:message code= "button.logout.label"/></a></h3>
    </form:form>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me find out how to redirect or forward.

Comment: There is a similar SO here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505894/spring-mvc-hibernate-id-to-load-is-required-for-loading

Comment: Make sure `${userForm.id}` is not null when in your registration jsp, debug you updateUser method it should return User with id

Comment: Dear  Õzbek, the problem is so:  if it enters the if block of updateUser method, the user gets null, and then I am not able to upload document,because I need user Id as request URL   "/add-document-{id}".

Comment: I understand that    [return "forward:/registration" ]  is not the best solution, but I really can't imagine how else  to render "registration" page in that case. If I replace it to [return "redirect:/registration"], nothing happens when I press any button.